# MySQL-Trying to add a multiple value option to insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a sign-up for people to subscribe to certain lists. I am trying to have a "Subscribe to All" option. Even when I list multiple values, only one list is subscribed to.
HTML:

```
<select name="lid">
    <option value="27:28:30">All Alerts</option>
    <option value="27">Child Care Alerts</option>
    <option value="28">Youth Basketball</option>
    <option value="30">Senior Wellness</option>
    </select>
```

And here is where I believe my problem lies in the code

```
@mysql_query("INSERT INTO `subscribers` (`id`, `listID`, `provider`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `number`, `ip`, `date`, `code`, `email`, `prefered_time`) VALUES (NULL, '$list', '$provider', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$number', '$ip', '" . date('n-j-Y H:i') . "', '$code', '$email', '$ptime')");
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `ar`, `instant` FROM `lists` WHERE `id` = '$list' AND `ar` = 'yes' AND `instant` = 'yes' LIMIT 1");
    $subID = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `subscribers` WHERE `listID` = '$list' AND `number` = '$number' LIMIT 1"));
```

I have tried taking out the "LIMIT 1", but that didn't do anything. It always subscribes to the lid=27

Please be gentle on me. I am a complete noob with this stuff.

Comment: What is the column type for `listID` ? Could it be `INT` or `INT(2)`, which would prevent `27:28:30` from being a valid entry, so it is truncated to just `27`

Comment: Do you intend to have "27:28:30" as the value in the `listID` field? Or do you want to enter three rows into the db, one for each subscription?

Comment: It is column type INT(11)

Comment: I want to enter 3 rows

Comment: Don't expect using `value="27:28:30"` that will auto populate itself into 3 columns.

Comment: It looks like you want to do something like `$lists=explode(":",$list); foreach($lists as $list){ mysql_query("INSERT INTO \`subscribers\` ....");}`

Comment: The explode code above still just puts it into the listID 27